# Help on Drupal table prefix

Tags: database

I just installed Drupal 7 and made some content and configuration.

After that, I just realized I did not put any table prefix on installation.

My problem is:

Is there anyone here that knows the SQL to add table prefix on Database `drupl`?

Example

- current table: variable
- must be: drupal_variable

I want to change all my table and add prefix.

Comment: I think this question might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824527/change-prefix-of-tables-once-platform-is-installed

Comment: I have an old script available [here](http://www.deuxcode.com/downloads/mysql-table-prefix-changer-dxc-version) that you can download and use to add table prefixes. Just remember to take a backup first (as always).

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to phpMyAdmin, you can do that manually following this steps:

1. Login to PhpMyAdmin
2. Select all drupal tables
3. With selected: Replace table prefix
4. From: *{empty}*, To: **yourprefix_**
5. in settings.php (sites/default/settings.php) change in the database configuration: `'prefix' => '',` to `'prefix' => 'yourprefix_',`
6. Run cron.

Comment: good solution. it will work

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER : Not a Drupal Developer, Just a MySQL DBA

You have a database called `drupl`

You want to prefix every table in that database with the `drupal_`

Here is the SQL to generate the script

```
SET @tableprefix = 'drupal_';
SET @dbtofix = 'drupl';
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',db,'.',tb,' RENAME ',db,'.'@tableprefix,tb,';')
FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=@dbtofix) A;
```

Here is how you script it in the OS

```
echo "SET @tableprefix = 'drupal_';" > Script.sql
echo "SET @dbtofix = 'drupl';" >> MakeScript.sql
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',db,'.',tb,'"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} RENAME ',db,'.'@tableprefix,tb,';')"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.tables"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema=@dbtofix) A"
mysql -u... -p... -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" >> MakeScript.sql
mysql -u... -p... < MakeScript.sql > AddPrefix.sql
mysql -u... -p... < AddPrefix.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!